# SSIS error when adding excel destination

Tags: sql, excel, ssis, sql-server-2012, data-conversion

I have a SSIS package with data in a SQL Server 2012 table have added an Excel destination and get the error

> There is no sufficient information about mapping ssis types to types of the selected .net data provider. As a result you may need to modify the default types of the SQL statement on the next screen

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE `Excel Destination` 
(
    `name` VARCHAR(50),
    `date` DATETIME
)
```

It doesn't like the 'name' column I have added a data conversion task but the 'name' column is already set to unicode string. So I'm not sure why I get message about converting between non unicode and unicode?

Any advice would be welcome.

Comment: you can mention the datatype as NVARCHAR(50) for the name, as you are loading unicode

Comment: yes i did try that before posting on here i still got the message about converting between non unicode and unicode

Answer (score 0):

Please check, This error is because your sheet is empty and there are no columns defined in it. you have to write the names of the column in the first row the target sheet.